# Finding eigenvalues using trace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix A is

$$A = \pmatrix  {1&1&1\\ 3&3&4 \\ 5&5&4}$$

Within the parentheses is each column.  It is given that one eigenvalue is -1.  It says to use the trace. I know how to set it up but I'm confused because there are two eigenvalues I need to find.

Comment: Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on this site so you can display matrices and other math symbols properly.

Comment: I hope the matrix A is correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

This matrix has rank $2$, hence its kernel is non-trivial.